# Animating a mask alongside an expanding CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, animation

I am working on a transition during which a collectionView cell expands to reveal new elements.

In order to prevent the new elements from animating with the cell, I removed them from the animated view.

[Here is an image of the view hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP7DK.jpg)

After I remove the elements from the animated view, they are also not being clipped by the cell anymore, revealing them before the cell has expanded.

Right now I can decide between the elements animating with the cell or the elements appearing before they should.

[Here is a video of the current state of the animation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0o4n4r9ehpcgxt/stack.mov?dl=0)

You can see the new elements appearing on the cell to the left of the selected one.

Below is the code for my animated transitioning:

```
    let destination = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) 
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

    containerView.addSubview(destination.view)


    // Initial state


    let widthConstraint = destination.header.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500)

    let heightConstraint =  destination.header.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 601)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([widthConstraint, heightConstraint])

    let transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(cellFrame.origin.x, cellFrame.origin.y, 0.0)


    destination.topView.layer.transform = transform
    destination.view.layer.zPosition = 999

    containerView.layoutIfNeeded()


    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 4, dampingRatio: 10) {

        // Final state

        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
        destination.topView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity

        destination.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

I was thinking about masking the new elements based on the frame of the expanding cell but am not sure how I could make that work.

Comment: Set `clipsToBounds` to true?

Comment: Hey matt, wouldn't that only work to clip a subview?

Comment: And the George is not a subview? What is it?

Comment: It used to be a subview but I took it out in order to prevent it from animating with the cell. Now it is the label inside of the "labeling" view.

Comment: But you are putting it back in. What are you putting it into?

Comment: It is the label inside of the "labeling" view.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see that in your code.

Comment: I created the UI in Interface Builder. As far as I know you would only see it in the image of the view hierarchy I linked to.

Comment: This is not making sense to me. I do not see how you can combine stuff configured in Interface Builder with a custom view controller transition animation. What kind of transition is this?

Comment: I am writing the animation within a class that conforms to UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning and am setting the LibraryViewController to be the transitioningdelegate in the prepare for segue function. It is a modal transition. I hope that answers your question, I just started learning a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it an it turned out to be easier than expected.

I simply created a mask based on the initial collectionViewCell and animated it to fullscreen alongside the expanding cell.

```
let mask = UIView()
        mask.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: cellFrame.origin.x, y: cellFrame.origin.y)
        mask.frame.size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 601)
        mask.backgroundColor = .white
        mask.alpha = 1
        destination.labelingView.mask = mask


// Final mask state
            mask.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            mask.frame.size = CGSize(width: 1366, height: 1024)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution you could do is to transition the labelingView to show only when it should be present. For example, only show your labelingView once you finish your animation transition.

Some psuedo code..

```
 labelingView.alpha = 0
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    // perform transitions
 }) { _ in
    labelingView.alpha = 1
 }
```

Comment: Animating the labelingView is a good idea! Still trying to figure out how to mask though, mostly to get a seamless transition of the logo.

Comment: You can also animate the labelingView's alpha back to 1 so it doesn't just magically appear.

Comment: I'd like the cellFrame to incrementally reveal the underlying labels in order to appear as if the user is looking through a window. If I would work with the alpha, the window would open up first and the label would appear once the the window is open. I am looking for a way to mask in order to have the labels appear as a result of the window opening.